# Recursive stream

Tags: java, file, recursion, java-8, java-stream

I want to list all the files on my computer recursively using Java 8.

Java 8 provides a `listFiles` method that returns all the files and directories but without recursion. How can I use it to get a full recursive list of files (without using a mutating collection)?

I've tried the code below but it only goes one level deep:

```
static Function<Path, Stream<Path>> listFiles = p -> {
    if (p.toFile().isDirectory()) {
        try { return Files.list(p); }
        catch (Exception e) { return Stream.empty(); }
    } else {
        return Stream.of(p);
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path root = Paths.get("C:/temp/");
    Files.list(root).flatMap(listFiles).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And using `return Files.list(p).flatMap(listFiles);` does not compile (not sure why)...

Note: I am not interested in solutions involving FileVisitors or external libraries.

Comment: `Files.walkFileTree` ? Or, do you really really just want to use a recursive stream? :-)

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes I just want to use a recursive stream! And walkFileTree is quite verbose so I was trying to find a "one-liner".

Comment: Whoops, I meant `Files.walk`. It takes a Path and returns a Stream<Path>.

Comment: Aha - I had completely missed that new method...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A new API to generate a stream of Paths by walking the filesystem recursively is `Files.walk`.

If you really want to generate a stream recursively (not necessarily walking the file tree, but I'll continue using that as an example), it might be a bit more straightforward to accomplish the recursion using method references:

```
class RecursiveStream {
    static Stream<Path> listFiles(Path path) {
        if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            try { return Files.list(path).flatMap(RecursiveStream::listFiles); }
            catch (Exception e) { return Stream.empty(); }
        } else {
            return Stream.of(path);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        listFiles(Paths.get(".")).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Method references turn out to be quite useful for adapting a named method that has the same "shape" (arguments and return type) as a functional interface to that functional interface. This also avoids the potential initialization circularity with storing a lambda in an instance or static variable and calling itself recursively.

Comment: Could there be a resource leak, if `Files.list` throws?

Answer (score 4):

It is apparently not possible to refer to a function within that function definition through a method reference but it works with a lambda.

So in the function, `return Files.list(p).flatMap(listFiles);` does not compile but `return Files.list(p).flatMap(q -> listFiles.apply(q));` does.

This prints all the files in the given folder recursively:

```
static final Function<Path, Stream<Path>> listFiles = p -> {
    if (p.toFile().isDirectory()) {
        try { return Files.list(p).flatMap(q -> listFiles.apply(q)); }
        catch (Exception e) { return Stream.empty(); }
    } else {
        return Stream.of(p);
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path root = Paths.get("C:/temp/");
    Files.list(root).flatMap(listFiles).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

---

but as pointed out, this is unnecessary:

```
Files.walk(root).forEach(System.out::println);
```

does the same thing...

Comment: It does not compile on JDK 8 b127 either: `Cannot reference a field before it is defined.`

Comment: Just to note: this relies on `listFiles` being a static field as shown in the example, and wouldn't work in other cases.  Even so, with the latest JDK, I couldn't get it to compile unless I first initialized the field to `null` and then turned around and re-initialized it with the lambda.  Of course, this all seems very smelly.