# Lazy BFS traversal of a tree-like structure using Stream API

Tags: tree, java-8, java-stream, lazy-evaluation, breadth-first-search

Consider I want to traverse some of the nodes of a tree-like structure using Stream API (similar questions: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158082), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646683), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956515)). The first implementation coming to mind would be:

```java
abstract class Node {
    abstract Collection<Node> getChildren();

    final Stream<Node> stream() {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), this.getChildren().stream().flatMap(Node::stream));
    }
}
```

The above `stream()` implementation has the following features:

- It's "almost lazy", in a sense that only the immediate children of the root node will be retrieved during a stream creation (children of other internal nodes will be queried as necessary).
- It exhibits a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) traversal order.

Now consider I have a large hierarchy, `getChildren()` operation is costly, and I'm looking for *any* `Node` matching some predicate:

```java
final Node tree = ...;
final Predicate<Node> p = ...;
tree.stream().filter(p).findAny();
```

1. How do I make my `stream()` implementation "completely lazy"? I don't want children of a node queried if the node itself already matches the predicate. I'm looking for a lazy version of `Stream.concat()` with a signature of `(Stream<T> a, Supplier<Stream<T>> b)`.
2. How do I implement a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) traversal order instead (using Stream API)?

Comment: Have you tried implementing a spliterator?

Comment: @the8472 That's what I'm about to do. Just was looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32656888/2711488). In short, the implementation is feasible and it’s not the `concat` (alone) but the *current implementation* of `flatMap` that affects the laziness. You have to think carefully whether you want to fix what the JRE broke. If you want to proceed, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32767282/2711488)…

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can only answer your first question. Again, `flatMap` is your friend here. It enables us to create a slightly different `concat` method that accepts stream-`Supplier`s instead of just streams:

```
abstract class Node {
    abstract Collection<Node> getChildren();

    Stream<Node> lazyTraverse() {
        return Node.concat(() -> Stream.of(this),
                           () -> getChildren().stream().flatMap(Node::lazyTraverse));
    }

    static Stream<Node> concat(Supplier<Stream<Node>> a, Supplier<Stream<Node>> b) {
        return Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(Supplier::get);
    }
}
```

An even better solution would be if you could replace `getChildren` by some mechanism that returns a lazy `Stream<Node>` instead and can be used directly in your original tree traversal algorithm. A lazy stream is much more suitable than a slow getter.

*Some words on your second question:*

I don't know if there is BFS traversal algorithm using the streaming-API in an elegant way, but I tend to say 'no' as BFS usually requires additional memory to store all nodes that have been visited but not yet traversed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Spliterators` library and the low level stream support primitives. You can then provide an `Iterator` over your nodes which does consume nodes only one by one.

```
return StreamSupport.stream( Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize( new Iterator<Node>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        // to implement
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public ContentVersion next()
    {
        // to implement
        return ...;
    }
}, 0 ), false );
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly, but this ought to work for Java 8:

```
public static <N> Stream<N> breadthFirst(N start, Function<? super N, Stream<N>> getChildren) {
    final LinkedList<Stream<N>> generations = new LinkedList<>();
    generations.add(Stream.of(start));
    final Iterator<Stream<N>> genIterator = createIterator(generations::remove, () -> !generations.isEmpty());
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(genIterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .distinct() // avoids loops
            .peek(n -> generations.add(getChildren.apply(n)));
}

public static <E> Iterator<E> createIterator(Supplier<E> supplier, BooleanSupplier hasNext) {
    return new Iterator<E>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return hasNext.getAsBoolean();
        }
        @Override
        public E next() {
            return supplier.get();
        }
    };
}
```

The idea here is that you need to hang onto references to subsequent generations, so we create a list to hold them while processing.  With Java 9 you'll be able to replace the custom iterator code with `Stream.generate(generations::poll).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method creating **lazy** `Stream` of tree structures using `Spliterator`

```
static <Z> Stream<Z> walk(Z object, Function<Z, Collection<Z>> childrenAccessor) {
    Collection<Z> zs = Collections.singletonList(object);
    return Stream.iterate(zs,
                          CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty,
                          o -> o.stream().map(z -> Objects.requireNonNullElse(childrenAccessor.apply(z), new ArrayList<Z>()))
                                        .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                 .flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

and you can use it this way:

```
Stream<Node> stream() {
    return walk(this, Node::getChildren);
}
```