# Recursive Sum of digits of number(until digit is less than 10) java 8 lambdas only

Tags: java, recursion, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am just practicing  lamdas java 8. My problem is as follows

Sum all the digits in an integer until its less than 10(means single digit left) and checks if its 1

**Sample Input 1**

```
100
```

**Sample Output 1**

```
1 // true because its one
```

**Sample Input 2**

```
55
```

**Sample Output 2**

```
1     ie  5+5 = 10 then 1+0 = 1 so true
```

I wrote a code

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList( String.valueOf(number).split("") ).stream()
                                                                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                                                    .mapToInt(i->i)
                                                                    .sum() == 1);
```

It works for the input 1 ie 100 but not for input 2 ie 55 which I clearly understand that in second case 10 is the output because the iteration is not recursive .

So how can I make this lambdas expression recursive so that it can work in second case also? I can create a method with that lambda expression and call it each time until return value is< 10 but I was thinking if there is any approach within lambdas.

Thanks

Comment: Your whole operation can be simplified to `number.codePoints().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum()`, but you can’t make it recursive without creating a named method.

Comment: @Holger There are [ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19429667/335858) of making recursive lambdas without making a named method. They do require a named variable, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: but using a named variable instead of a named method does not offer any advantage, but produces an additional stack frame in every recursive step, compared to ordinary recursion…

Comment: @Holger Absolutely! I am not saying it *should* be done, only that it *can* be done.

Comment: @Holger you mean `String.valueOf(number.codePoints().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum()` thanks for the help this would be my second question to shorten the code you made my day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a pure lambda solution, you should forget about making it recursive, as there is absolutely no reason to implement an iterative process as a recursion:

```
Stream.iterate(String.valueOf(number),
               n -> String.valueOf(n.codePoints().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum()))
      .filter(s -> s.length()==1)
      .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/iI8slY)

Answer (score 3):

Making lambdas recursive in Java is not easy because of the "variable may be uninitialized" error, but it can be done. Here is a [link to an answer describing one way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25473855/335858).

When applied to your task, this can be done as follows:

```
// This comes from the answer linked above
class Recursive<I> {
    public I func;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Recursive<Function<Integer,Integer>> sumDigits = new Recursive<>();
    sumDigits.func = (Integer number) -> {
        int s = Arrays.asList( String.valueOf(number).split("") )
            .stream()
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .mapToInt(i->i)
            .sum();
        return s < 10 ? s : sumDigits.func.apply(s);
    };
    System.out.println(sumDigits.func.apply(100) == 1);
    System.out.println(sumDigits.func.apply(101) == 1);
    System.out.println(sumDigits.func.apply(55) == 1);
    System.out.println(sumDigits.func.apply(56) == 1);
}
```

I took your code, wrapped it in `{` ... `}`s, and added a recursive invocation on the `return` line.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/I0ievI)

Comment: Since the problem isn’t recursive, I added a much simpler solution. As far as I can see, most questions about making lambdas recursive are actually an XY problem.

Comment: @Holger I very much doubt that people are trying to solve actual problems with recursive lambdas. I think that most questions about recursive lambdas are driven by pure curiosity: programmers who are learning a new  and exciting tool, are naturally trying to see how far they can push it. As it turns out, one can push it pretty far :-)

Comment: But these attempts lead into the wrong direction. People pushing things that far, tend to use the same unnecessarily complicated solutions in real life code. I’ve seen such code…